# Область видимости у указателей в C++, автоматическая или статическая?

Tags: c++, указатели, область-видимости

У переменных и констант вроде понятна область видимости, а вот у указателей(которые хранят адрес ячейки памяти) какая область видимости- автоматическая или статическая?

Comment: то есть указатель удалится после блока функции или циклов?

Comment: Указатель - это тип. Тип переменной никогда не влияет на область видимости.

Comment: Что за чушь? *Область видимости* не бывает "автоматической" или "статической". Ничего подобного в С++ нет. Область видимости любой сущности зависит от того, где она объявлена. "Автоматической" или "статической" бывает *продолжительность хранения* (storage duration). Но и она зависит от того где и как объявлена переменная. От типа все это никак не зависит и указатели тут ничем не выделяются.

Answer (score 12):

Указатель, как переменная - несомненно, выделенный блок памяти, на который он указывает - нет.

```
void f()
{
    int *p;
    p = new int[100];
}
```

По выходе из функции переменная `p` как таковая будет удалена; блок, на который она указывала - нет (в данном случае продемонстрирована утечка памяти).